# when will `git ls-remote -q origin` be executed when `go build` using go module?

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci, go-modules

My gitlab build pipeline was failed, for it would run `git ls-remote -q origin` directive, and reported an error saying that "The project you were looking for could not be found".

```
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]  /go/pkg/mod/***/finance/alice@v0.9.63-0.20211231031838-f6dae3fdb8c4/kafkax/kafka_consumer.go:9:2: reading golang.***.com/kit/swimlane/go.mod at revision v0.0.1: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/d59e078efe804645d7b0bc877750c96d810a57328e3acc47eb94bdb969209bf9: exit status 128:
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]   > GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]   
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
[2022/01/04 15:58:00]   and the repository exists.
```

Actually, the "swimlane" dependency, which was not an go module project, had been already downloaded.

```
[2022/01/04 15:57:39] go: downloading golang.***.com/kit/swimlane v0.0.1
[2022/01/04 15:57:39] get "golang.***.com/kit/swimlane": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.***.com/kit/swimlane", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"git+ssh://git@git.***.com/kit/swimlane"} at //golang.***.com/kit/swimlane?go-get=1
```

However, for some reason I had not figured out, it seemed like it was the "/kafkax/kafka_consumer.go:9:2" that caused it to run "git ls-remote -q origin" to get remote references available for "swimlane".

I used `git ls-remote --get-url origin` to get the origin url, which is "http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.***.com/finance/order-center.git". "finance/order-center.git" was this exact project the gitlab pipeline was failed building, but not the origin of "swimlane".

I'm looking for a way to make my pipeline run successfully. It will be very appreciated to share your opinion or solution to this problem.

thank you!!!

P.S. The original git config was:

```
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] Step 12/22 : RUN git config --list
[2022/01/04 15:57:18]  ---> Running in 3170cf53e18e
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] url.http://git.***.com/.insteadof=git+ssh://git@git.***.com/
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] fetch.recursesubmodules=false
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] core.repositoryformatversion=0
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] core.filemode=true
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] core.bare=false
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] core.logallrefupdates=true
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] remote.origin.url=http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@git.***.com/finance/order-center.git
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] branch.master.remote=origin
[2022/01/04 15:57:18] branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

to use ssh to fetch code from private repo, I RUN

```
[2022/01/04 15:57:23] Step 20/22 : RUN git config --global --unset url.http://git.***.com/.insteadof
```

Comment: everything was fine with my local IDE environment...

Answer (score 0):

you can check this code
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b1a53ece68d46e4fb59c74d2bc529060861f5dbf/src/cmd/go/internal/vcs/vcs.go#L242-L246
generally, git ls-remote will be called when go get or download the mod(go build will download remote module that deps by current build).

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand why it would get or download the mod "swimlane" when checked or scanned (or do something with?) the code of "kafkax/kafka_consumer.go:9:2" where the package was used. The mod "swimlane" was required in the main mod and had been downloaded before... And it was required in the finance/alice mod, which was also a main mod dependency... And what was the cause of the re-downloading of the mod swimlane??

Comment: is the swinlane mod is a private repo in your company's gitlab? It could be cause by that you can not access to to the swinlane repo.